# C# - Find items in ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, filter, listbox, observablecollection

I'm trying to add a **"Search"** feature for my **Listbox** which I've binded to using **ObservableCollection** but I don't know how I can do that.

**For my ObservableCollection**:

```
ObservableCollection<ItemProperties> ItemCollection { get; set; }
public class ItemProperties : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public ItemProperties() { }

        private string m_ID;
        public string ID
        {
            get { return m_ID; }
            set
            {
                m_ID = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ID");
            }
        }

        private string m_Title;
        public string Title
        {
            get { return m_Title; }
            set
            {
                m_Title = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Title");
            }
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
```

**I load my Items to the Listbox**:

```
        string[] fileNames = isf.GetDirectoryNames("Files/*.*");
        ItemCollection = new ObservableCollection<ItemProperties>();
        foreach (var Directory in fileNames)
        {
            // code which reads and loads the text files to string which then is added to the Collection
        }
        ItemCollection.Add(new ItemProperties { ID = a_ID, Title = a_Title});
        IEnumerable<ItemProperties> query = ItemCollection.OrderBy(Dat => Dat.Title);
        listBox1.ItemsSource = query;
```

Now I have a button which enables a TextBox. When the TextBox is enabled and as I type, listBox1 should only show what I typed. If what I typed doesn't exist then the Listbox shouldn't show the items. e.g.:

[image]

How can I do this and have such a feature? I want it to be like the Windows Phone app search.

**Delete Method (using Context Menu):**

```
 var contextMenuOpenedIndex = listBox1.Items.IndexOf((sender as MenuItem).DataContext);
 ItemCollection.RemoveAt(contextMenuOpenedIndex);
```

When i click on the delete button, it deletes another item keeping the one I really want to delete.

Comment: Off the top of my head, a `TextBox` I think has something like a "Changed" event which fires each time you type. In there you can filter the full list by what is in the box. This should make it change as you type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider making use of a [CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.data.collectionviewsource.aspx) as your data source instead of using your ObservableCollection directly. You can declare this object as a XAML element or dimension it in code behind. Refresh the view whenever you encounter an appropriate UI event, such as your search box losing focus or a key being pressed, whichever meets your desired UI responsiveness.

```
private CollectionViewSource MySource { get; set; }

private void PopulateView()
{
    string[] fileNames = isf.GetDirectoryNames("Files/*.*");
    ItemCollection = new ObservableCollection<ItemProperties>();
    foreach (var Directory in fileNames)
    {
        // code which reads and loads the text files to string which then is added to the Collection
    }
    ItemCollection.Add(new ItemProperties { ID = a_ID, Title = a_Title});

    // Create view
    MySource = new CollectionViewSource {
        Source = ItemCollection
    };

    // Add sorting support
    MySource.View.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Title", ListSortDirection.Ascending));

    // Create a filter method
    MySource.View.Filter = obj => 
    {
        var item = obj as ItemProperties;

        // Predicate to determine if search box criteria met; change as needed
        return item.Title.Contains(txtMyFilter.Text);
    }

    // Initialize selected item to avoid SelectionChanged event
    MySource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst()

    // Set as ListBox source
    listBox1.ItemsSource = MySource.View;
}

// Bind to XAML TextBox element's KeyUp event or similar
private void OnFilterKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    MySource.View.Refresh();

    // Include any other display logic here, such as possibly scrolling to top of ListBox
}
```

Regarding your deletion code, I would not encourage you to try and line up indices. Try instead:

```
ItemCollection.Remove((sender as MenuItem).DataContext as ItemProperties);
```

Comment: Why does it give me a :Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) on listBox1.ItemsSource = Mysource?

Comment: @F4z Apologies, that should have been `listBox1.ItemsSource = MySource.View`. I've updated the answer to reflect that fact. The property is of type [`ICollectionView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview(v=vs.110).aspx) which implements both `IEnumerable` and `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

Comment: It filters! that's great however I have two problems. First problem is that it when I search for a quey and it shows up, I can't delete that item. the other problem is that for some reason, when the page is loaded, listBox1_SelectionChanged event is triggered. I've updated the answer a little bit which shows my delete method.

Comment: @F4z Had a quick look at your delete. Don't try to match indexes. Remove the item by reference. See my code edit for an example.

Comment: I'm getting an exception: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<main.p_Menu.ItemProperties>.Remove(main.p_Menu.ItemProperties)' has some invalid arguments `and` Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'main.p_Menu.ItemProperties'

Comment: @F4z Right, that was just because I didn't cast DataContext to type ItemProperties. Made another edit, but the error is right in the description.

Comment: Thank you! it works perfectly! Everything! as for the listbox selection changed event, I took out the code I had which was navigate to a certain page but looks like the selection event is getting triggered without me selecting it. Could it be the CollectionView doing something? Happens at launch

Comment: @F4z After checking around the site, it seems that the View's CurrentItem doesn't start out initialized. Try calling [MoveCurrentToFirst](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.movecurrenttofirst(v=vs.110).aspx) before assigning it to the ItemsSource. I'll update the code.

Comment: Thank you for everything but I think a better way is to use the listbox TAP event. This way I'm VERY sure that only the user made the tap and not the code.